# SharePoint: Order list by date

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

New to SharePoint.
I would like to retrieve items from a "Page" in reverse date order.

This the code I am using to obtain the details from the pages. It is currently populating the list by page order created but would like to have it sort the list by listing the most recently added item to the top of the list.

```
var listTitle = "Pages";

function getEvents() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('https://int-canada.wrberkley.com/resources');
    //alert("1");
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle); 
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery()
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View></View>");
    namedListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(namedListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var count = 0;
    var count = namedListItem.get_count();
    if (count < 1) {}
    else
    { 
        var ctrl = document.getElementById("Company Resources");
        var listItemTR = "<tr><td>{1}</td><td><a href='{2}'><h2>{3}</h2></a><br />{4}</td></tr>";
        var listItemInfo = "";
        var listItemEnumerator = namedListItem.getEnumerator();
        var CT = 0;
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            var newsTitle = oListItem.get_item('Title');
            if (newsTitle != 'Home')  //Do not include "default.aspx"
            {
                var newsComment = oListItem.get_item('Comments');
                var newsImageURL = oListItem.get_item('PublishingRollupImage');
                var newsFileRef = oListItem.get_item('FileRef');

                var strResult = listItemTR;         
                strResult = strResult.replace("{1}", newsImageURL);
                strResult = strResult.replace("{2}", newsFileRef);
                strResult = strResult.replace("{3}", newsTitle);
                strResult = strResult.replace("{4}", newsComment);  
                listItemInfo += strResult;
            }
        CT +=1;
        if (CT > 1){
        break;}
        }


        ctrl.parentNode.innerHTML = "<table>" + listItemInfo + "</table>";
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) sample from the site:

```
//array of objects
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];

//underscore in action
_.sortBy(stooges, 'name');

//output
=> [{name: 'curly', age: 60}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'moe', age: 40}];
```